# QApplication::setWindowIcon works in Release & Debug but not on other computers

Tags: netbeans, qt4, mingw

I have a small Windows application with an icon for the title bar and it **works** correctly on my development machine (release & debug), but it does **not work** on other machines.  In general, my Qt 4.8.5 code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(gcapp);
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./gc.ico"));
    GCApp dialog;
    dialog.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I have tried many iterations using options such as:

```
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("gc.ico"));
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/gc.ico"));
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":gc.ico"));
```

I have also tried adding gc.ico in the NetBeans project's Resource Files section.  I have edited the Project Properties, Custom Definitions (these change the .pro file) and tried the following:

```
RC_ICONS = gc.ico
RC_ICONS += gc.ico
win32:RC_ICONS = gc.ico
```

Most of the combinations of everything said above shows the gc.ico file in the title bar of release and debug executables on the development machine.  None of them work on other machines.

I am including gc.ico in the directory on the target machines along side of the release executable.

Comment: What are these "other machines"? Do they have support for the .ico graphics format? Does it work if you use .png instead?

Comment: All the target machines and my development machine are Windows 10 PCs.  I originally used .gif and later switched to .ico before making this post.  Do you suggest that .png might yield different results than .gif and .ico?

Answer (score 0):

First of all read about [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/resources.html).

You should add your `gc.ico` under qt resources control. Then you can be able set the application icon with something like this:

```
app.setWindowIcon("qrc:///icons/gc.ico");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answer did not solve the problem.  I'm quite familiar with the Qt Resource System and reread it many times even since the post.  When I put the icon into the qrc file (which puts it into the pro file), I see the release executable size increase by 10kB.  The qrc:/// nomenclature does not work on my PC or others.  QIcon() calls using :/ : ./ and no prefix all work on my PC, but not on others.  I have a sample project illustrating the issue, but Stackoverflow does not permit attachments.  I can host it elsewhere if anyone is interested.